# Logrotate not rotating or creating new files

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, logging, logrotate

I'm trying to setup logrotate for apache on my Ubuntu server, however I keep getting the following errors when attempting to test the rotation:

```
logrotate_script: 4: logrotate_script:  : not found
error: error running shared prerotate script for '/var/log/apache2/*.log '
```

I've ran it in debug, verbose and force mode but I can't seem to see anything that clearly points me to the issue, so I'd greatly appreciate any help.

Here is my `/etc/logrotate.d/apache2` file:

```
/var/log/apache2/*.log {
        size 100k
        missingok
        rotate 14
        compress
        delaycompress
        notifempty
        create 640 root adm
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                /etc/init.d/apache2 restart > /dev/null;
        endscript
        prerotate
                if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then \
                        run-parts /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate; \
                fi; \
        endscript
}
```

Here is the output from running the command `sudo logrotate -vf /etc/logrotate.d/apache2`:

```
reading config file /etc/logrotate.d/apache2
Handling 1 logs
rotating pattern: /var/log/apache2/*.log  forced from command line (14 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/apache2/access.log
  log does not need rotating
considering log /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log
  log needs rotating
considering log /var/log/apache2/error.log
  log needs rotating
considering log /var/log/apache2/error_proxy.log
  log does not need rotating
considering log /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log
  log needs rotating
rotating log /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log, log->rotateCount is 14
dateext suffix '-20190122'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
previous log /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.1 does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.14.gz to /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.15.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 14), 
old log /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.14.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.13.gz to /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.14.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 13), 
old log /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.13.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.12.gz to /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.13.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 12), 
old log /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.12.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.11.gz to /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.12.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 11), 
old log /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.11.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.10.gz to /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.11.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 10), 
old log /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.10.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.9.gz to /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.10.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 9), 
old log /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.9.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.8.gz to /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.9.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 8), 
old log /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.8.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.7.gz to /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.8.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 7), 
old log /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.7.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.6.gz to /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.7.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 6), 
old log /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.6.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.5.gz to /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.6.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 5), 
old log /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.5.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.4.gz to /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.5.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 4), 
old log /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.4.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.3.gz to /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.4.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 3), 
old log /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.3.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.2.gz to /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.3.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 2), 
old log /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.2.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.1.gz to /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.2.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 1), 
old log /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.1.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.0.gz to /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.1.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 0), 
old log /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.0.gz does not exist
log /var/log/apache2/access_proxy.log.15.gz doesn't exist -- won't try to dispose of it
rotating log /var/log/apache2/error.log, log->rotateCount is 14
dateext suffix '-20190122'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
previous log /var/log/apache2/error.log.1 does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/error.log.14.gz to /var/log/apache2/error.log.15.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 14), 
old log /var/log/apache2/error.log.14.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/error.log.13.gz to /var/log/apache2/error.log.14.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 13), 
old log /var/log/apache2/error.log.13.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/error.log.12.gz to /var/log/apache2/error.log.13.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 12), 
old log /var/log/apache2/error.log.12.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/error.log.11.gz to /var/log/apache2/error.log.12.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 11), 
old log /var/log/apache2/error.log.11.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/error.log.10.gz to /var/log/apache2/error.log.11.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 10), 
old log /var/log/apache2/error.log.10.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/error.log.9.gz to /var/log/apache2/error.log.10.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 9), 
old log /var/log/apache2/error.log.9.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/error.log.8.gz to /var/log/apache2/error.log.9.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 8), 
old log /var/log/apache2/error.log.8.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/error.log.7.gz to /var/log/apache2/error.log.8.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 7), 
old log /var/log/apache2/error.log.7.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/error.log.6.gz to /var/log/apache2/error.log.7.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 6), 
old log /var/log/apache2/error.log.6.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/error.log.5.gz to /var/log/apache2/error.log.6.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 5), 
old log /var/log/apache2/error.log.5.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/error.log.4.gz to /var/log/apache2/error.log.5.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 4), 
old log /var/log/apache2/error.log.4.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/error.log.3.gz to /var/log/apache2/error.log.4.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 3), 
old log /var/log/apache2/error.log.3.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/error.log.2.gz to /var/log/apache2/error.log.3.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 2), 
old log /var/log/apache2/error.log.2.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/error.log.1.gz to /var/log/apache2/error.log.2.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 1), 
old log /var/log/apache2/error.log.1.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/error.log.0.gz to /var/log/apache2/error.log.1.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 0), 
old log /var/log/apache2/error.log.0.gz does not exist
log /var/log/apache2/error.log.15.gz doesn't exist -- won't try to dispose of it
rotating log /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log, log->rotateCount is 14
dateext suffix '-20190122'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
previous log /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.1 does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.14.gz to /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.15.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 14), 
old log /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.14.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.13.gz to /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.14.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 13), 
old log /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.13.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.12.gz to /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.13.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 12), 
old log /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.12.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.11.gz to /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.12.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 11), 
old log /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.11.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.10.gz to /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.11.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 10), 
old log /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.10.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.9.gz to /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.10.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 9), 
old log /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.9.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.8.gz to /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.9.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 8), 
old log /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.8.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.7.gz to /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.8.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 7), 
old log /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.7.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.6.gz to /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.7.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 6), 
old log /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.6.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.5.gz to /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.6.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 5), 
old log /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.5.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.4.gz to /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.5.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 4), 
old log /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.4.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.3.gz to /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.4.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 3), 
old log /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.3.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.2.gz to /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.3.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 2), 
old log /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.2.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.1.gz to /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.2.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 1), 
old log /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.1.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.0.gz to /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.1.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 0), 
old log /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.0.gz does not exist
log /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log.15.gz doesn't exist -- won't try to dispose of it
running prerotate script
logrotate_script: 4: logrotate_script:  : not found
error: error running shared prerotate script for '/var/log/apache2/*.log '
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks :)

EDIT: bump

Answer (score 0):

This is a little confusing but is /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate a file you're attempting to execute? Per run-parts [man](https://man.cx/run-parts(8))

> run−parts [−−test] [−−verbose] [−−report] [−−lsbsysinit] [−−regex=RE] [−−umask=umask] [−−arg=argument] [−−exit−on−error] [−−help] [−−version] [−−list] [−−reverse] [−−] **DIRECTORY**

If you're passing a single file to run-parts, it's not going to know what to do with it. Just set that file executable and call it directly, i.e.

```
prerotate
  if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then
    /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate;
  fi;
endscript
```